# Dispaly custom attribute on catalogpage

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, category-products, custom-attributes

On catalog page, I want to display custom attribute (**code=inhoud2**) near each product. I have tried to fetch it in different ways, 
it works with other attributes with plain text fields but for attributes by which a value has to be chosen in the backend from a Dropbox
it will return a number instead of the chosen option.

Can anyone help me with this?
(Option "**Used in Product Listing**" and show on front end is set to Yes for this attribute).

methods I have used so far in the list.phtml are:

**returns nothing**

```
<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getInhoud2(), 'inhoud2') ?>
```

**returns numeric value**

```
<?php echo $_product->getData('inhoud2'); ?>
```

**returns numeric value**

```
<?php echo $_product->getData('inhoud2'); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, found it

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('inhoud2') ?>
```